# How to solve permission error while testing drf view?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, pytest

I am getting permission error `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'authenticators'` while testing my drf view. I am using `djangorestframework-api-key` for rest framework permission.
**views.py**

```py
class SliderViewSet(RetrieveModelMixin, ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Slider.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SliderSerializer
    lookup_field = "id"
```

**test_view.py**

```py
class TestSliderViewSet:
    @pytest.fixture
    def api_rf(self) -> APIRequestFactory:
        return APIRequestFactory()

    def test_get_queryset(self, slider: Slider, api_rf: APIRequestFactory):
        view = SliderViewSet()
        request = api_rf.get("/fake-url/")
        view.request = request

        assert slider in view.get_queryset()
    
    def test_get_object(self, slider: Slider, api_rf: APIRequestFactory):
        from rest_framework_api_key.models import APIKey
        api_key, key = APIKey.objects.create_key(name="my-remote-service")

        view = SliderViewSet()
        request = api_rf.get("/fake-url/")
        request.META['X_API_KEY'] = f'Api-Key {key}'

        view.request = request
        view.kwargs = {"id": slider.pk}

        assert slider == view.get_object()
```

if I remove `rest_framework_api_key.permissions.HasAPIKey` from `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` test is done successfully.